# How Anonymous class different from other classes in Java?

Tags: java, class, anonymous-class

I know that Anonymous class does'nt have any name.
It is used inside the Simple classes.But more than this,how Anonymous classes are different from Simple classes we use?

Comment: They differ by not having a name. What's your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anonymous classes are the same as local classes except they don't have a name.
They are expressions not declarations. So it will be part of a staement (i.e. the statement which creates the object and so we are placing a semicolumn after an anonymous class definition). You can use an anonymous class if you need to use it only once.

Major points:

1. You cannot declare a constructor inside it.
2. Can access all class level variables of the enclosing class and only final local variables.
3. Cannot declare static initializers, but can have static variables which are declared as final also.

In Java 8 lambdas are having similar syntax to anonymous classes and they can replace anonymous classes if you need a stateless implementation.

Answer (score 0):

They are mostly used in UI programs to handle events. If your class/interface does a little functionality then instead of creating new file for it you embed it in the existing class. You can find elaborate description on https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html.